# Sum of digits with test cases in C

Tags: c, sum-of-digits

I am trying to find the `sum` of digits with test cases. But the problem is after I find one `sum`, this `sum` is adding to the next `sum` but I only one particular `sum` of that numbers' digit. Please help. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int t, n, i, r, sum=0;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    for(i=0; i<t; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        while(n>0) {
            r = n % 10;
            sum = sum + r;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And Here is my output:

```
3
1234
10
2347
26
8744
49
```

Why my previous `sum` adding to the next `sum`? I am not understanding.

My desired output:

```
3
1234
10
2347
16
8744
23
```

Comment: In addition make `r = 0` also

Comment: reset the value of `sum` on every iteration you take new user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

Your variable `sum` is set to `0` on the start of the program and you are adding the sum of each test case in the same variable without cleaning the result of the previous test case (by setting `sum = 0` before the next test case starts.)

**Possible Solution:**

Initialize your your variable `sum` before a test case starts.

**Code:**

```
for(i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &n);

    sum = 0; //Set sum = 0

    //Test Case started in while loop
    while(n>0) {
        r = n % 10;
        sum = sum + r;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the begining of your loop set `sum` to `0`. So that before taking sum over next set of elements it is reinitialized to zero.

```
for(i=0; i<t; i++) 
  { 
    sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `sum=0;` on the first line of the `for` loop.